# How can I organize better these two consecutive IF statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic, boolean-logic

I would like to organize better the following two `if` statements:

```
if(A || B){
    do stuff...
}

if(A && ! B){
    do other stuff...
}
```

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**: `!` before `B` on second statement, sorry...

Comment: A||B will evaluate to true when A&&B is true as well. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot the ! operator before the B on the second IF statement. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if( A || B ) {
    do some stuff;
    if( !B ) {
        do other stuff;
    }
}
```

But the benefits depend on the usage, it could be harder to understand this version.

Comment: Someone finally get it, thought I cannot see the advantage:) +1

Comment: @Ziyao, yeah, me too, just answered the question :D

Comment: Well the advantage now is that the performance of the code is better now that I avoid an evaluation of A. Not only, the code is simplified, being avoided a second typing of an arbitrarly complex A expression. The disadvantage is that I gained an additional nesting level.

Comment: @francesco, performance benefits are zero as optimizer does it differently anyway, typing `A` for the second time is not an issue when code becomes harder to understand. The readability should be the foremost concern, really.

Answer (score 2):

For the original question, where the second condition was A && B, my answer is:

If nothing else, you can nest the second block inside the first, to prevent unnecessary evaluation if the first condition fails. Otherwise, I don't see any good way to shorten this... and nesting assumes the code in the first block doesn't update A and B, and it might.

For the new question, my answe is to embed a block in the first one that checks !B, and omit the second block. This is equivalent to another answer that was given for the new question.

Comment: My answer is no longer relevant since the OP changed the question.

Comment: Then it is better to edit or delete it, rather than adding a comment.